# How to use DRI_PRIME automatically from launcher

Tags: shortcuts, hybrid-graphics, .desktop

[image: DRI_PRIME]

I thought something like the command ("komut" in picture)in the desktop launcher from attached picture but it doesn't work unfortunately.You get what i intend to do i hope. so how do i make that work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command should be:

```
env DRI_PRIME=1 steam steam://rungameid/227300
```

From `env` man page:

> ```
> NAME
>        env - run a program in a modified environment
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        Set each NAME to VALUE in the environment and run COMMAND.
> ```

Comment: I am using Photoshop CS6 using playonlinux. Is there a similar way to use DRI_PRIME for playonlinux installations? Thanks :)